# PHP Search txt file dosen't look on the first line

Tags: php

Ive got this bit of code to look in my txt file to see if i already have the item, However it never looks on the first line. Is there something i can do to fix this?

```
<?php
for($i=0, $count = count($match[1]);$i<$count;$i++) {
$filename = 'alreadyadded.txt';
$searchfor = $match[1][$i];
$file = file_get_contents($filename);
    if(strpos($file, $searchfor)) {
       echo $match[1][$i]." Is already added, No Actions needed. <br />";
    } else {
        echo "grabbing this one".$match[1][$i]."<br />";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: why $match[1], shouldn't it be $match[0]?

Comment: No? i want to check the contents of $match[1] as thats whats been written into the text file.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it this way:

```
if(strpos($file, $searchfor) !== false) {
   echo $match[1][$i]." Is already added, No Actions needed. <br />";
} else {
    echo "grabbing this one".$match[1][$i]."<br />";
}
```

if the position found is 0 (the first character) you basically get wrong result. You want to compare the result to false including datatype.

0 == false returns true

0 === false returns false

0 != false returns false

0 !== false returns true

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve the problem but should make it slightly faster. You don't need to read the file each time.

```
$filename = 'alreadyadded.txt';
$file = file_get_contents($filename);
for($i=0, $count = count($match[1]);$i<$count;$i++) {
    $searchfor = $match[1][$i];
    if(strpos($file, $searchfor)!==false) {
       echo $match[1][$i]." Is already added, No Actions needed. <br />";
    } else {
        echo "grabbing this one".$match[1][$i]."<br />";
    }
}
```